# How can I map 2 non-hierarchical classes to the same table with a defining column & value in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent

So there is a way to map 2 hierarchical classes in EF to the same table with a defining column and value (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#2.4). I am wondering if there's a way to map 2 non-hierarchical classes to the same table in the same manner.

Example:

```
class User
    Guid Id
    string Name
    Guid? GroupId

class Group
    Guid Id
    string Name

Table
    uid Id PK
    varchar Name
    bit IsGroup
    uid GroupId nullable
```

I can't change the schema of that table, so the only solution I've come up with so far is to create a view for User and a view for Group.

Comment: Well, you're going to have troubles with any table that doesn't have a primary key in EF

Comment: Introduce an abstract base type. But is this really the table schema? Is `Name` the primary key?

Comment: @Gert No, I simplified the scenario quite a bit for the question. It's terrible the way that they're mixed in the schema. There is an actual PK on the table, but that's not very relevant to the question. My issue isn't getting the relationship between them mapped, it's mainly the fact that 2 non-hierarchical entities (User and Group do not inherit from the other) are stored in a single table and differentiated only by the IsGroup column. It's just one of the many things about this terrible and dated schema that we're eager to change, but are unable to right now.

Comment: Edited the question with some additional detail.

Answer (score 0):

Mo,

I think that at the end of the day you are after a user group that contains the users that belong to it. If that's the case here is something that will get you started. Remember that this is not meant to be a "best practice" just an example to get you up and running. you will need to tweak this code for your exact situation.

Here's the basic jest of it. You need to give group a property of type List...then the populate the list of users from a database query. In the below example I wrote a method that handles populating the list. However in practice you don't have to do populate the list here you could instantiate the userGroup and populate the list of users from inside an action method. Like I said this in not a best practice just a quick example.

Here is an example.

```
    public class userGroup
    {
        class user
        {
            private int id { get; set; }
            private string name { get; set; }
            private Guid grpId { get; set; }

            public int userId { get { return id; } set { id = value; } }
            public string userName { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }
            public Guid groupId { get { return grpId; } set { grpId = value; } }
            public user() { }
        }

        class group
        {
            private Guid id { get; set; }
            private string name { get; set; }

            public List<user> usersInGroup = new List<user>();
            public Guid groupId { get { return id; } set { id = value; } }
            public string groupName { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }
            public group() { }
        }

        public userGroup() { }

        public group getUserGroup() 
        {
            group x = new group();
            Guid newGroupId = Guid.NewGuid();
            x.groupId = newGroupId;

            var userQuery = myDB.Where(n => n.myField == myConditon).Select(n => new
            {
                n.userId,//I'm assuming that the database query returns a field userId
                n.userName//I'm assuming that the database query returns a field userName
            });

            foreach(var user in userQuery)
            {
                userGroup.user y = new userGroup.user();

                y.groupId = newGroupId;

                y.userId = user.userId;
                y.userName = user.userName;

                x.usersInGroup.Add(user);    
            }

            return x;
        }
    }
```

I hope that I understood your question and that my example points you in the right direction.
Best wishes,
Bill

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty easily model this by introducing an abstract base type from which both types derive.

```
public abstract class BaseNamedEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Group : BaseNamedEntity
{
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User : BaseNamedEntity
{
    public Guid GroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

In the context you tell that `IsGroup` is the discriminator:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<BaseNamedEntity>().ToTable("MyTable");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Group>().Map(m => m.Requires("IsGroup")
                    .HasValue(true));
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Map(m => m.Requires("IsGroup")
                    .HasValue(false));
    }

    public DbSet<BaseNamedEntity> BaseNamedEntities { get; set; }
}
```

I don't think that `BaseNamedEntity` is a particularly good name, so maybe you have to come up with something more meaningful.